# Do a CURL post using PHP?

Tags: curl

I have the following curl command that works perfectly from the windows command line:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X PUT -d   "{\"name\":\"Name\",\"password\":\"1234\",\"email\":\"somebuy@bla.com\"}"   http://localhost:8080/users
```

So the jSon for this post is:

```
{\"name\":\"Name\",\"password\":\"1234\",\"email\":\"somebuy@bla.com\"}
```

I try to execute it using the following PHP Code:

```
$ch = curl_init(); // initialize curl handle
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // set url to post to
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); // Fail on errors
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // allow redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); // return into a variable
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $port); //Set the port number
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5); // times out after 5s
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
if (!empty($request)) {
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);   
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($request)); // add POST fields
}

if($port==443) {
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
}

$data = curl_exec($ch); // if($data === false) echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
$error = curl_errno($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if ($error) {
  $error_codes = $this->_get_curl_error_codes();
  echo
    'Sorry, but we are currently not able to connect to the database. Error code '.$error.': '.$error_codes[$error];
  die();
}
```

I use this code as follows:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/users';
$port = 8080;
$request = array();
$request['name']        = 'Name';
$request['password']    = '1234';
$request['email']       = 'somebuy@bla.com';
```

Json is created like so:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($request)); // add POST fields
```

My problem is that if I run it from the command line, it works, but if I run it using the code above, it doesn't work. Any ideas why?

Comment: after curl_exec uncomment this  echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);

Comment: also what this means $this->_get_curl_error_codes(); ? 
you script is not a part of class so this would raise an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

curl command from console is using PUT, you are using POST

try next options

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$json);
```

example http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2009/putting-data-fields-with-php-curl

if it doesn't work, also add headers

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($json)));
```

One more thing: 
there is a  `$this->_get_curl_error_codes();` but I didn't notice such method in your code

Comment: Now i'm getting "Request Entity Too Large"

Comment: Ended up at a "method now allowed" error, but seems I'm on the right path now. I was missing the "PUT" part completely...

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you

```
function get($url, $params=array()) {   

  $url = $url.'?'.http_build_query($params, '', '&');
  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

  $response = curl_exec($ch);

  curl_close($ch);

  return $response;

}
```